# Run selenium tests in Gitlab-CI (maven and java)

Tags: java, docker, selenium, maven, gitlab-ci

I have a Maven project with some tests (Selenium + Java + Junit + Cucumber)

The tests run correctly in my localhost.

I try to run these tests in Gitlab CI. I created `.gitlab-ci.yml` in my project's root:

```yaml
image: markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-16
    
stages:
  - build
  - test
    
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
    
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS clean package
    - mvn compile
    
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
```

My piece of java code with WebDriver:

```java
   public static void setUp() {
        System.setProperty(getChromeProperty(), getUserDirectory() + "/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        chromeOptions.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
```

When I run this in Gitlab CI I get errors in build stage:

```
"[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.106 s <<< FAILURE! - in runners.TestRunner
[ERROR] Login #6.ALT_1 TestCase_1  Time elapsed: 1.352 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /builds/ALT-Tests/MyApp/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe
```

How can I resolve this? Is the driver hidden for `/builds` directory in docker?

Comment: First separating the step `compile` and `test` does not makes sense in Maven. Furthermore if you try to execute a file which is intended for Windows (chromedriver.exe) assumes that you have an OS available which can execute that. As you mention you are running inside Docker...Are those docker images Windows images ? And are you running on a Windows system?

Comment: You are running selenium on a linux image, so .exe won't work. Plus, the docs clearly states that you need to run in `headless` mode.

Comment: @aksappy: it is exactly as you write. How can i manage with this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that you were setting headless option later in the code. Can you set the chrome driver to `/usr/bin/chromedriver` instead of the .exe file that you are using? The docker image has it bundled already.

Comment: @aksappy, khmarbaise: Ok, when I changed source chrome driver to: /usr/bin/chromedriver everything works perfect only on .gitlab-ci.yml. With source: getUserDirectory() + "/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe" everything works perfect only for Windows.  I need a condition that identifies the system and select the appropriate driver path. What's the best way to do this? And where to add it? In .gitlab-ci.yml file or in my Java code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have answer for my question.

To sum things up:

- locally I run my tests on Windows system
- Gitlab CI runs on Docker: Linux system

I have hard coded path to ChromeDriver (it's problem):

```
   System.setProperty(getChromeProperty(), getUserDirectory() + "/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
```

To resolve:

- on Windows I added new environment variable. Variable name: WEBDRIVER ,variable value: `C:\Users\test\IdeaProjects\myProject\src\test\resources\drivers\chromedriver.exe`
- in my java code I changed path to Chrome driver (read from environment variable)

  System.setProperty(getChromeProperty(), System.getenv("WEBDRIVER"));

Windows is done.

To run on linux I added in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
    before_script:
      - export WEBDRIVER="/usr/bin/chromedriver"
```

Everything works :)